# Term for weak head normal forms that cannot be reduced in any environment

Tags: terminology, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, normal-forms

In my understanding, a lambda expression is a **normal form** (NF) when it has no redexes. For instance, $\lambda x.x$ is a NF, but $(\lambda x.x)y$ is not. A lambda expression is a **weak head normal form** (WHNF) if the root expression is not a redex. For instance, $\lambda x.(\lambda y.y)x$ is a WHNF, but not a NF as it reduces to $\lambda x.x$.

When implementing functional programming languages we call the opposite of an expression in WHNF a **thunk**. Thus, taking Haskell as an example, `const 1 2` is a thunk (it evaluates to `1`), but `const`, `const 1` and `(1,const 1)` are WHNFs (the first two are unsaturated applications; the last is a constructor).

I'm looking for term to distinguish `const (1,2)` and `(1,const 1)`. They are both WHNFs, neither is in NF, however, the root constructor of the latter (`(,)`) will not change any more while that of the former (`const`) may still change, if it is applied to some other expression (to `(,)`). Are there terms that distinguish WHNFs of which the head can/cannot change in any environment?

Comment: What you are calling "head normal form" is actually weak head normal form. See, e.g. page 5 of [Demonstrating Lambda Calculus Reduction](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/papers/sestoft-lamreduce.pdf#page=5).

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks for clarifying that for me! I updated the question.

Comment: If you claim that "`const 1` may change" because we could apply it to `2`, then you also have to agree that `const (1, 2)` may change because we could apply `fst` to it. I do not understand your question. And the title of your question is odd, did you mean "evaluation context" instead of "environment"? An environment is a mapping of variables to their values, but you are talking about closed expressions which are completely independent of the environment.

Comment: @AndrejBauer yes, I agree, I didn't think of it that way. I suppose then what I'm looking for is "a WHNF that can be applied" vs. "a WHNF that cannot be applied". I suppose there are no terms for that? Perhaps you could add your comment as an answer. It doesn't answer the question directly, but does explain why it is a weird question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to make application special. So of all eliminator forms applying to a term is special. It would be helpful to know the motivation for this. Where are you going with this?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don't think it's the application, rather the abstraction. The application is not a WHNF, but the abstraction is a WHNF that can be applied. I don't think there is a real equivalent in the lambda calculus, but in real-world FP languages this is opposed to constructors which are WHNF but cannot be applied in a way that their head is rewritten. The context is that I'm writing a paper on serialization of FP expressions, and these two cases are handled differently. It would be nice if there was a short common term (otherwise we'll coin a new one).